Запуск tg bot + fast api
Возникла такая необходимость при создании проекта. У меня есть fastapi магазин, где пользователь добавляет товары в корзину и отправляет. Так же есть tg_bot, данное fastapi будет работать как tg WebApp, мне необходимо отправлять заявки в отдельный канал. Как мне реализовать запуск и fastapi и tg_bot совместно, ChatGPT предложил вариант, запускается и работает все хорошо, но никак не получается отключить в последующем, в терминале ctr + c не срабатывает и все зависает
tg_bot.py
import asyncio
import signal
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, html
from aiogram.client.default import DefaultBotProperties
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, WebAppInfo

TOKEN =''
CHANNEL_ID = ''
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def command_start_handler(message: Message) -> None:
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        inline_keyboard=[
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text="Оформить заказ",
                    web_app=WebAppInfo(url=f"https://..io"),
                )
            ]
        ]
    )
    await message.answer("По кнопке ниже вы можете оформить заказ!", reply_markup=markup)
    
    # Отправка сообщения в канал
    await send_message_to_channel(dp.bot)

async def send_message_to_channel(bot: Bot) -> None:
    await bot.send_message(CHANNEL_ID, "Пользователь ввёл команду /start")

async def start_bot() -> None:
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN, default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML))
    dp.bot = bot
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

# Обработчик завершения для Telegram бота
shutdown_event = asyncio.Event()

# Обработчик сигналов
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print(f"Received signal: {sig}. Shutting down...")
    shutdown_event.set()

for sig in (signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM):
    signal.signal(sig, signal_handler)

async def shutdown():
    await shutdown_event.wait()
    dp.bot.session.close()

main.py
import asyncio
import signal
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

from app.api.router import router as router_api
from app.api.tg_bot import start_bot, shutdown_event  # Импортируйте ваш Telegram-бот

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Выполняем действия перед запуском приложения
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    bot_task = loop.create_task(start_bot())
    
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        # Выполняем действия при завершении приложения
        shutdown_event.set()  # Сигнализируем о завершении
        bot_task.cancel()
        try:
            await bot_task
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass  # Ожидаем завершения задачи бота

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

app.mount('/static', StaticFiles(directory='app/static'), 'static')

app.include_router(router_api)

